# Hyperbolic functions proof using $\cosh x$

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

> Prove that $\cosh x-1\equiv \frac12(e^{0.5x}-e^{-0.5x})^2$

I'm stuck on what appears to be the last step, please could someone explain where I have made a mistake?

\begin{align}
\frac12(e^{0.5x}-e^{-0.5x})^2 & \equiv \frac12(\sinh(0.5x))^2 \\
& \equiv \frac12\sinh^2(0.5x) \\
& \equiv \frac12(\cosh^2(0.5x) -1) \\
& \equiv \frac12((\frac{e^{0.5x}+e^{-0.5x}}{2})^2 -1) \\ 
& \equiv \frac12((\frac{e^x+e^{-x}+2}4) -1) \\ 
& \equiv \frac14((\frac{e^x+e^{-x}+2}2)-2) \\ 
& \equiv \frac14(\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}2+\frac22-2) \\
& \equiv \frac14(\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}-1) \\
& \equiv \frac14(\cosh x-1) \\
\end{align}

which is a quarter of what I am trying to prove?

Comment: $$e^{\frac12x}-e^{-\frac12x}=\color{red}2\sinh \frac12x$$

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with your multiplicative factors! In the very first step, you should have written
$$\frac12(e^{0.5x}-e^{-0.5x})^2=\color{red}2(\sinh0.5x)^2$$
With this correction, the rest of your steps check out and you get the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\begin{align}
\frac12(e^{0.5x}-e^{-0.5x})^2 & \equiv \frac12(2\sinh(0.5x))^2 \\
& \equiv 2\sinh^2(0.5x) \\
& \equiv 2(\cosh^2(0.5x) -1) \\
& \equiv 2((\frac{e^{0.5x}+e^{-0.5x}}{2})^2 -1) \\ 
& \equiv 2((\frac{e^x+e^{-x}+2}4) -1) \\ 
& \equiv ((\frac{e^x+e^{-x}+2}2)-2) \\ 
& \equiv (\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}2+\frac22-2) \\
& \equiv (\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}-1) \\
& \equiv (\cosh x-1) \\
\end{align}$$ Which is what you wanted to prove.